# Create a custom filtered object using map, filter etc

Tags: javascript, data-structures, functional-programming, iteration, reduce

How can I transform a collection like this where I want to filter out the months where show is false and create a nice clean object using functional methods?

```
    var monthsInYearModel = [
        {'year':'2016', 'months': [
          {name: 'Jan', show: true, num: 0},
          {name: 'Feb', show: false, num: 1},
          {name: 'Mar', show: true, num: 2}
           ...until dec...
       ]}
    ];
```

This is an example of the structure I'm trying to create by only using array methods like map, filter, reduce etc?

```
{
   '2016':{
             'jan':0,
             'mar':2,
           ...until dec...
          }
}
```

This is my attempt but I'm getting too many arrays back

```
     var keyCodeYear = '2016'

     var years = monthsInYearModel
     .filter( obj => obj.year == keyCodeYear )
     .map( obj => obj.months.filter(month => month.show) );

{
   [
   '2016':[
            {name:'jan', num:0 },
            {name:'mar', num:2 }
            ...until dec...
          ]
   ]
}
```

[here's a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oYHmsTfL5K5CzTNOr5hj?p=preview)

Comment: you need `reduce` instead of `map`.  `map` is always one-to-one.  But you want to *reduce* into an object at each level.

Comment: Sorry output is to console at the moment : S

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var years = (mnths => ((obj, key, val) => (obj[key] = val, obj))({}, keyCodeYear, mnths) )(
  (arr => arr[0].months.filter(month => month.show).reduce((res, obj) => (res[obj.name] = obj.num, res), {}))(
     monthsInYearModel.filter(obj => obj.year == keyCodeYear)
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var monthsInYearModel = [{
  'year' : '2016',
  'months': [
    { name: 'Jan', show: true, num: 0 },
    { name: 'Feb', show: false, num: 1 },
    { name: 'Mar', show: true, num: 2 }
  ]
}, {
  'year': '2017',
  'months': [
    { name: 'Jan', show: false, num: 0 },
    { name: 'Feb', show: false, num: 1 },
    { name: 'Mar', show: false, num: 2 }
  ]
}, {
  'year': '2018',
  'months': [
    { name: 'Jan', show: false, num: 0 },
    { name: 'Feb', show: true, num: 1 },
    { name: 'Mar', show: true, num: 2 }
  ]
}];

// expected
// {
//   '2016': {
//     'jan': 0,
//     'mar': 2
//   }, ...
//


function aggregateYearsIndexWithNonEmptyFilteredMonthLists(collector, yearItem/*, idx, list*/) {
  var
    yearsIndex  = collector.yearsIndex,
    monthList   = yearItem.months.filter(collector.monthCondition);

  if (monthList.length >= 1) {
      yearsIndex[yearItem.year] = monthList.reduce(collector.aggregateMonths, {});
  }
  return collector;
}


var yearsIndex = monthsInYearModel.reduce(aggregateYearsIndexWithNonEmptyFilteredMonthLists, {

  monthCondition  : function(monthItem/*, idx, list*/) {
    return monthItem.show;
  },
  aggregateMonths : function (monthsIndex, monthItem/*, idx, list*/) {
    monthsIndex[monthItem.name.toLowerCase()] = monthItem.num;
    return monthsIndex;
  },
  yearsIndex  : {}

}).yearsIndex;


console.log('yearsIndex : ', yearsIndex);
```

**additional note** / *edited*

In case the OP just wanted a reduced data structure for a certain year, `monthsInYearModel` just needs to be filtered before accordingly. The rest still gets covered by the above provided solution ...

```
var yearsIndex = monthsInYearModel.filter(function (yearItem) {

    return (Number(yearItem.year) == 2016);

}).reduce(aggregateYearsIndexWithNonEmptyFilteredMonthLists, {

  monthCondition  : function(monthItem/*, idx, list*/) {
    return monthItem.show;
  },
  aggregateMonths : function (monthsIndex, monthItem/*, idx, list*/) {
    monthsIndex[monthItem.name.toLowerCase()] = monthItem.num;
    return monthsIndex;
  },
  yearsIndex  : {}

}).yearsIndex;


console.log('yearsIndex : ', yearsIndex);
```

Comment: @Mangopop ... in addition to the above provided solution I did update your "plunker" source as well.